# Delegates in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, protocols

I am using custom Kal calender view library downloaded from github. I know very well and execute successfully how to create delegate protocol and implement them.
But now in my application I have to do, when user click on date that date directly reflect to my UIViewController class. For that scenario I used `@protocol` delegate method but I got strange problem in it. Please see the following screenshot and suggest me where I am wrong,
[image]

[image]
Then i synthesize my protocol
[image]

[image]

but I got the below error. Why, where I am wrong?

Comment: Clean all project and rebuild all. Does it help?

Comment: @Toro, yes sir i cleaning all my target even though i reset my simulator also, but it continue....

Comment: It is really strange. How about renaming the protocol of `KalViewControllerDelegate` to something else ? I guess that maybe it has been used in iOS SDK and there are some conflicts about the name of protocol.

Comment: I am curious about the renaming works or not. :) If it works, please let me know.

Comment: @Toro, yes also renaming protocol name but same result as before. I think i happen due to

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6783/discussion-between-rrb-and-toro)

Comment: I modify my answer, hope it can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I downloaded the [Kal from github](https://github.com/klazuka/Kal). After reading the sample it provides, I am curious how you embedded the `Kal` into your project.

As the sample project inside `Kal`, it embedded the `Kal` into project as the following image. And it imports the header named `Kal.h` in `NativeCalAppDelegate.m`. So, there may be something wrong about the setting of header search path for `Kal` inside your project. If you compiler the `Kal` into a static library, how you reference the header files of `Kal` ?

[image: Kal sample project]

**Edit**

I modify the example of `NativeCal` and upload the whole `Kal project` to [this link](http://www.box.com/shared/ctfb4zylpfq8pu882d4v), which is downloadable.

It is successful to compile. The followings are some images about what I modified.

`About KalViewControllerDelegate inside the header`
[image: The declaration of KalViewControllerDelegate]

`Declare the implementation of KalViewControllerDelegate`
[image]
[image]

**Edit Final**

I finally found out why the `NativeCal` can import header correctly. It did the settings after import the xcode project as following images. 
[image]
[image]

Comment: thanks for updating your answer. I really lucky i got your guidance. But now i change my design, now i using apple classic GUI UIDatePicker instead of kal custom calender library.

Comment: Today, I finally know why the `NativeCal` sample project imports those header files correctly. I modified the answers again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to #import the .h header file where you have declared your `KalViewControllerDelegate` protocol.

Comment: you mean i have to import 'ScheduleViewController' my custom UIViewController class inside KalViewController where i declare protocol??????

Comment: It's hard to tell from your screenshots which code belongs to which files.  But the error message seems to indicate that the protocol declaration exists in a location unknown to the file where the error appears.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that will help, but when I used Kal I did it that way:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "SomeOfMyClasses.h"
#import "Kal.h"

@interface SomeRandomViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, KalViewDelegate>
```

as you can see, I used KalViewDelegate and not KalViewControllerDelegate. Also don't forget to import "Kal.h".

**Update**

I did the following in my viewDidLoad method:

```
self.kvc = [[KalViewController alloc]init];
self.kvc.delegate = self;
self.kvc.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 340);
```

and header file:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) KalViewController *kvc;
```

Comment: i think you right, but how i trace kal.h delegate methods using KalViewController ???

Comment: if you want to do something when the date is tapped, just use '-(void)didSelectDate:(KalDate *)date' method.

Comment: ok. But before this i have again need to allocate and initialize then set Kal delegate... i m already   allocate and initialize KalViewController class????????

Comment: u cannot set self.kvc.delegate = self; becoz, delegate is already protocol declare for UITableViewDelegate.

Answer (score 0):

Haha i was very curios about why you couldnt make it, so i decided to download the class myself. Funny thing is i DIDNT get any problems.

Here is what i did:

(i assume you want to create a new protocol for the class KalViewController.h)
so you add

Bellow the "@class KalLogic, KalDate;"

```
@protocol KalViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)dateDidSelected:(NSDate *)selectedDate;

@end
```

then in the SAME header file where the properties are declared you add:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<KalViewControllerDelegate> delegate2;
```

Please note that this header already has a delegate implemented

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<UITableViewDelegate> delegate;
```

so you have to name it something else other than delegate.

then on the implementation file of that class you syntethize that name:

```
@synthesize dataSource, delegate, initialDate, selectedDate, delegate2;
```

and then you can implmeneted that delegate whever you want. I have no idea what this kal project does so i picked a random file (in this case SBJSON.h)

and added the (on the header)

```
@interface SBJSON : SBJsonBase <SBJsonParser, SBJsonWriter, KalViewControllerDelegate> {
```

and (on the implementation)

```
- (void)dateDidSelected:(NSDate *)selectedDate
{

}
```

Hope this helps, Good luck